# How to use access django template variable in a separate js file rather than inlcuding small script block in same html file?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-templates

I am not able to access template variables passed from views.py file in django. I coudldn't find any answer on stackoverflow yet. I have tried everything like converting the variable to json object and parsing it in the separate js file.

How to access the template variable from views.py in a separate .js file ?
Please help.

Comment: Why not make a specific view that returns JSON blobs, and let JavaScript trigger the specific view (perhaps with some parameters)?

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Write a .js template and render that file from your view.

Comment: I have  a simple application with single page only. If I will make a separate .js template how will I be able to use django for processing. If I'm not clear in explaining, please excuse me. I am a total beginner. I have to use django for my machine learning model.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `window.variable` and then you'll have access to it.

In the template:

```
<script>
  window.variable_x = '{{ variable_x_from_view_ctx }}`
</script>
```

Then in your JS file:

`const variable_x = window.variable_x`

Comment: I don't want to use script block. Thank you for the answer though.